# Are variable evaluations pushed by 'eas secret:push'?

Tags: eas

Are variable evaluations pushed by `eas secret:push`?

For example, if I have a `.env` with something like

```bash
CHAT_TOKEN_TESTER='A....'
CHAT_TOKEN_USER='B....'
CHAT_TOKEN_USER='C....'
CHAT_TOKEN=$CHAT_TOKEN_TESTER
```

then when I `eas secret:push` will the value of `CHAT_TOKEN_TESTER` (`'A...'`) be pushed as the value of `CHAT_TOKEN`?